# mysql_connect(): Access denied for user

Tags: mysql, database, connection

I am getting this weird error message
    **`mysql_connect():`** Access denied for user 'spaceagent_dk@10'@'10.246.64.59'
I don't have any clue of how to fix it and I don't understand why it "breaks" in the middle.

And on top the last part 10.246.64.59 are not my server and are nowhere in my code. Anybody can help me?
Thanks a lot. I have tried to find answers all over. I guess I am not that experienced yet... 
Best,
Louise

Comment: ..... Is the login information for the `mysql_connect()` correct? also you need to use `mysqli_connect` now days the older one is deprecated.

Comment: I just tried to the mysql_connect and I get the same error. I am providing the right login information; my_user@10.246.16.251 and it is not what is typed in the error message? I have looked for those numbers (the wrong ones) in my code and they are nowhere...

Comment: I mean the mysqli_connect  ;)

Comment: Double check your server to maker sure your user has the privileges to connect to the database. Just because you can login into the server backend, it doesn't mean the user is part of the database.

Comment: Ok. How do I do that? I am using the username provided from the backend, but it might not have the right privileged. That I'm not sure of, though...

Comment: I don't know what type web host you are using. You need to figure that one out yourself.

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. It's awful and is being removed in future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). A guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) can help explain best practices. Always be absolutely **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will have severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).